# How to run EWS Java API with Java 6

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, java-6, exchange-server-2010, ewsjavaapi

I am using EWS Java API to connect Exchange Server. The Java version in my compile and runtime environment is 1.6.0_26.

When the application starts, it gives an error and the program exits. It says that `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`. So isn't it possible to use this EWS library with Java 6, do I have to use Java 7 to make it run? (Because of some limitations, I am not able to switch Java 7 right now.) Please help me to find a way to work with Java 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Switched to JWebServices for Exchange (JDK 5)